# PGDatasource won't connect to remote server

Tags: spring, postgresql, ssl, datasource

I'm trying to implement a listener for postgresql. When a get the database connection it will work fine if i'm connected to my localhost, but once i change the host to a remote server it will fail.

```
@Bean
public DataSource datasource(){
    PGDataSource pgDataSource = new PGDataSource();
    pgDataSource.setHost( hostname );
    pgDataSource.setDatabase( database );
    pgDataSource.setPassword( password );
    pgDataSource.setPort( Integer.parseInt(port) );
    pgDataSource.setUser( user );
    return pgDataSource;
}
```

application.yml

```
pg:
 connection:
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pwd: test
  usr: test
  dbs: test
  port: 5432
```

When I run the listener with those properties it works fine, but once i change the host it fails. I think it might be the ssl, but there is no method to set the ssl to true.

Comment: Please post the error you receive when trying to connect to the remote server?

Comment: com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGSQLSimpleException: Connection Error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<host>", user "<user>", database "<password>", SSL off --

I talked to a DBA and he told me I had to enable ssl, the problem is that **com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource** doesn't seem to have the option to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to solve the error. I just had to enable the ssl in one of the properties. I was looking for a setter for the ssl in the PGDataSource, but as I didn't find any method to do it, I enable it in the database name.

I did the following:

```
pg:
 connection:
  host: remote-host
  pwd: test
  usr: test
  dbs: test?ssl.mode=require
  port: 5432
```